# Function with location data not populating for lighting mapping

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I wanted to create a function inside a different JS file called "MapMarkers.js", and then call that function to main JS file called "mapping.js". Importing the function to the main JS file seems like it working correctly. It's just seems like the "mapMarkers" property from the isn't reading the data?

**If helpful here's the Map documentation:**

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-map/documentation

**mapMarkers.js Code**

```
export function MapMarkers(SearchCity, SearchState, SearchStreet){

    [
        {
            location: {

                City: SearchCity,
                Country: 'USA',
                State: SearchState,
                Street: SearchStreet,
                // PostalCode: ,
            },

            value: 'location001',
            title: 'Headquarters',
            description: 'Headquarters',
            // fillColor: '#CF3476',
            
        },

        {
            location: {

                City: 'Boston',
                Country: 'USA',
                State: 'MA',

            },

            value: 'MA_HQ',
            title: 'MA Headquarters',
            
        },

    ];

}
```

**mapping.js Code**

`mapMarkers = MapMarkers(SearchCity, SearchState, SearchStreet);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

***Needed to include:***

const mapMarkers = [

&

return mapMarkers;

```
const mapMarkers = [
        {
            location: {

                City: SearchCity,
                Country: 'USA',
                State: SearchState,
                Street: SearchStreet,
                // PostalCode: ,
            },

            value: 'location001',
            title: 'Headquarters',
            description: 'Headquarters',
            
        },

        {
            location: {

                City: 'Milford',
                Country: 'USA',
                State: 'MA',
                // Street: '1224 abc St',

            },

            value: 'WES_MA_HQ',
            title: 'Headquarters',
            description: 'Headquarters',
            fillColor: '#CF3476',
            
        },

    ];

    return mapMarkers;

}
```